# Service invoked too many times in a short time: exec qps. (Google Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Recently some of my app scripts are showing errors when executed simultaneously. Everything worked fine for years, apparently the change happened on Google side.

This is the execution transcript result: 
[image]

Unfortunately, the error does not show file name and line number to debug it properly, but my first line is:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
```

Therefore I assume that calling SpreadsheetApp simultaneously by instances of the app is causing the error. SpreadsheetApp is not in the loop, nor inside any function. It is called to define global variable ss to be used by the app.

My apps are executed under my user name, since users should not have access to the Spreadsheet I'm accessing. I'm afraid I can't keep the entire Spreadsheet in Cache Service - I want app to update the Spreadsheet when it it called.

UPDATE:

Here is some relevant code from one of the apps.

```
function doGet(e){

  var ref = e.parameter.ref;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('########')
  var logsheet = ss.getSheetByName('LOG');
  logsheet.appendRow([new Date(),ref,JSON.stringify(e.parameter)])
  try{
     //Main code goes here
     return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({result:"ok"})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }catch(e){
     return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)}
}
```

As you can see I have try {} catch(e) in my function, and since the error I'm getting is not caught by it, I assume it happens right before.

Comment: Can you share more lines of code from your script.

Comment: Hi Amit, I was learning a lot from your examples, thank you!

I added an example code. Error happens before the main execution even starts, which suggests that there is something to deal with SpreadsheetApp calls. Sometimes my App is called 20-30 times per minute. Not such a big deal, should be handled properly, imo. At least it worked well for a couple of years.

Answer (score 2):

Just discovered manual hack to avoid this error:

Open your spreadsheet from private browser mode. This will increase number of document viewers and will increase limits :)

Answer (score 1):

You can put everything in the try-catch block. Also remember to publish a new version of the web app before execution.

```
function doGet(e) {
    var response = {};
    try {
        SpreadsheetApp.openById('########')
            .getSheetByName('LOG')
            .appendRow([new Date(), e.parameter.ref, JSON.stringify(e.parameter)]);
        response.result = "OK";
    } catch (error) {
        response.result = "Error: " + error.toString();
    }

    return ContentService
        .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(response))
        .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, actually this was the first thing I tried, but it did not work. As you can see, if error is caught within the function - it should return JSON with error details as string, but what I'm seeing is google's script web-page with error message. Therefore, error happens out of the scale. I will try to grab the screenshot. It looks like not only SpreadsheetApp, but several urlFetch calls are also triggering this error.

Comment: The quota limits are available at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas

Comment: There is no explicit quota on the amount of concurrent apps executions. Moreover, the error I'm getting is "exec qps" - does not correspond to any known service. I have noticed, that at night time, when my users are out of the office I'm not getting this error.

Comment: I guess I'm probably starting to hit the max amount of users who can simultaneously use my apps. I have about a dozen of apps and they are using a couple of spreadsheets as database, I tried to optimise it and also implemented caching service a few months ago, but apparently, it comes close to limits when I start doing some batch tasks. Probably, I should consider moving to App Engine...